# AlarmManager service invocation not working

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I am trying to run a service on a specific time every day (i.e. 11 am) using the `AlarmManager`. But for some reason my code is not working.

**AlarmManager**

```
public class ScheduleHelper {

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     * @param hourOfDay
     */
    public static void scheduleDayly(Context context){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        schedule(context, intent, cal, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, 1337);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     * @param calendar
     */
    private static void schedule(Context context, Intent intent,
            Calendar calendar, long alarmManagerTimeInterval, int requestCode) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                requestCode, intent, 0);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Running in " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-calendar.getTimeInMillis()) + " ms", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManagerTimeInterval,
                pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

**NotificationService**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("Service", "service created");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i("Service", "service started");

            //Todo: create notification
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("Service", "service destroyed");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("Service", "service start command received");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
}
```

According to LogCat the service is never created or started (I also tried to set the calendar 5 minutes past now with the same result)

Can you please give me tips what I am doing wrong? Reading through the several questions about the same topic here unfortunately didn't help to fix the problem.

Comment: have You added Your service inside manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a service with pending intent, use :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,
            requestCode, intent, 0);
```

This is when you want to broadcast something from your Pending Intent.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                requestCode, intent, 0);
```